# How to prevent top-level bootstrap nav bar items from changing url

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm putting together Angular app, in which I'm trying to utilize a bootstrap nav bar in the following way:

```
<div class="navbar" >
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <!--<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">-->
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse" >
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Customer Instances <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#/itarList">iTAR</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/nonItarList">Non-iTAR</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Training & Documentation <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#/videoTutorials">Video Tutorials</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/taskBasedHelp">Task-Based Help</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/documentTemplates">Document Templates</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/artifactSamples">Artifact Samples</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Service Requests <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#/viewExistingRequests">View Existing Requests</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/enterNewRequest">Enter New Request</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Development Tracker <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#/viewBacklogItems">View Backlog Items</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/viewFeatureReleaseSchedule">View Feature Release Schedule</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/viewListOfSuggestedEnhancements">View List Of Suggested Enhancements</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/suggetAnEnhancement">Suggest An Enhancement</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/viewActiveBugReports">View Active Bug Reports</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#/reportABug">Report A Bug</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Site Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#/userAdministration">User Administration</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/instanceAdministration">Instance Administration</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#/applicationAdministration">Application Administration</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As it stands, there is an undesirable behavior: when the top-level nav item (such as "Customer Instances" or "Training & Documentation") is clicked, the page url is being immediately reset to the "MainPage", even before any navigation selection is made.
I'm asking to advise on how to prevent this behavior.

Comment: What does "reset to the 'MainPage'" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete all `href="#"` parts. According to [ui-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), you can then add styling to those elements:

```
.nav, .pagination, .carousel, .panel-title a { cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: Do you see any way to use href="#" in angular?

Comment: Removing the href removes the undesirable effect, but also forces the user to click on the tiny glif in order to unfold the dropdown. What styling class can I use to compansate for that and make the entire surface of the top-level item clickable?

Comment: licancabur put me on the right track - all I had to do is to remove the # from each <a> and leave the rest as-is.